# Area estimation with scipy.integrate.dblquad

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to calculate areas using `scipy.integrate.dblquad`, but I just don't understand this result (integral of a circle with radius 1):

```
import scipy.integrate as integ

def cercle(x,y):
    if x**2+y**2<=1 : return 1
    else : return 0 


In [12]: integ.dblquad(cercle, -1,1, lambda y: -1,lambda y:1)
Out[12]: (1.5248947619635096, 4.083599258741799e-08)
```

Why do I not get the right area?

Answer (score 2):

Works "OKish" here, but could probably use a better routine.

python 2.7.9

scipy 0.14.1

```
>>> def c(x,y):
...     if x**2+y**2<=1:
...         return 1
...     else:
...         return 0
... 
>>> c(2,2)
0
>>> c(.5,.5)
1
>>> from scipy.integrate import dblquad
>>> dblquad(c, -1, 1, lambda y: -1, lambda y:1)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py:321: IntegrationWarning: The maximum number of subdivisions (50) has been achieved.
  If increasing the limit yields no improvement it is advised to analyze 
  the integrand in order to determine the difficulties.  If the position of a 
  local difficulty can be determined (singularity, discontinuity) one will 
  probably gain from splitting up the interval and calling the integrator 
  on the subranges.  Perhaps a special-purpose integrator should be used.
  warnings.warn(msg, IntegrationWarning)
(3.1421278363209537, 0.0002045333175209052)
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the expected answer when I run your code.

```
>>> def cercle(x,y):
...     if x**2+y**2<=1 : return 1
...     else : return 0 
... 
>>> integ.dblquad(cercle, -1,1, lambda y: -1,lambda y:1)
(3.1421278363209537, 0.0002045333175209052)
```

Check the code you ran originally; if you have a typo in one of your arguments it may explain your error. **For example, changing the first limit of integration to .1 instead of -1 results in:**

```
>>> integ.dblquad(cercle, .1,1, lambda y: -1,lambda y:1)
(1.3711257717509415, 5.8123454403774075e-05)
```